# Соединение сущностей через виртуальные коллекции

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется EF6 Code-First. Так-же имеются сущности File и Error:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext {
    // ...
    public virtual DbSet<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        // ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Error>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Files)
            .WithMany(e => e.Errors)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("FileError").MapLeftKey("ErrorId").MapRightKey("FileId"));
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

public partial class File {
    public File() {
        Errors = new HashSet<Error>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public partial class Error {
    public Error() {
        Files = new HashSet<File>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

В результате в БД создаются 3 таблицы: Files, Errors и промежуточная таблица FileError. Для экспорта в Excel мне необходимо иметь экземпляр List или DataTable. Было бы неплохо использовать Join через промежуточную таблицы, но сущности для нее нет. 
Моя проблема заключается в непонимании того, как создать запрос на выборку всех файлов с ошибками:

```
// Возвращает сущности Error.
// Для доступа к свойствам File нужно перебирать 
// свойство Files в каждой записи.
var q = from e in Errors
        where e.Files.Count > 0
        select e;

// а хотелось бы...
var q = from e in Errors
        join f in Files in f.Errors equals e.Files
        select new {
            FileId = f.Id,
            ErrorId = e.Id,
            FilePath = f.FullPath,
            ErrorDescription = e.Description
        };
```

Comment: а почему Вы не хотите использовать *навигационные свойства*? получаем необходимый список, через *навигационное свойство* получаем ошибку/ошибки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете писать столько операторов `from`, сколько вам нужно - на это нет ограничений:

```
var q = from e in db.Errors
        from f in e.Files
        select new {
          FileId = f.Id,
          ErrorId = e.Id
        }
```

Такая вложенность при компиляции заменится на использование метода SelectMany. Также его можно и самостоятельно вызвать, если такой вариант больше нравится:

```
var q = db.Errors.SelectMany(e => 
          e.Files.Select(f => 
            new { FileId = f.Id, ErrorId = e.Id }
          )
        );
```

Следует понимать, что такой вариант приведет к внутреннему соединению. То есть если у сущности `Error` нет связанных файлов - она не попадет в итоговую выборку. Если вам нужен аналог левого внешнего соединения (LEFT JOIN) - следует использовать `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
var q = from e in db.Errors
        from f in e.Files.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
          FileId = f?.Id,
          ErrorId = e.Id
        }
```

Если вы используете старый C#, где нет оператора `?.` - надо привести `f.Id` к типу `int?`, в противном случае свойство FileId компилятор сгенерирует типа `int` - и при попытке записи туда пустого значения возникнет ошибка.

Полного аналога полного внешнего соединения (FULL OUTER JOIN) в linq нет, но можно сделать LEFT JOIN, а потом отдельно добавить файлы без ошибок.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это именно то, что я искал!

Answer (score 0):

Вот выбор всех файлов с ошибками

```
Files.Where(x => x.Errors.Count>0)
```

Comment: Мне необходимо выбрать файлы с ошибками и описанием этих ошибок. В предложенном варианте мы получаем только список файлов, без описания ошибок.

Comment: @XelaNimed все ошибки находятся в свойстве `Files[*].Errors`

Comment: Я в курсе. Проблема была в том, как выбрать без использования циклов.

Comment: @XelaNimed Я и не говорил, что нужно массивы использовать. Чем вас не устраивает необходимость обращения к ошибкам через свойство?

Comment: "... необходимость обращения к ошибкам через свойство" - как раз этим самым. Приведите свой пример или отредактируйте уже существующий, который бы возвращал List со свойствами обеих сущностей, чтоб было понятно о чем Вы говорите.